# AttributeError: 'Web3' has no attribute 'shh'

Tags: ethereumjs, web3.py

Web3.py version: 4.2.1
Python: 3.5.2
OS: linux
geth version: 1.8.0-unstable

I am running geth with --shh flag and --rpcapi "admin,eth,net,web3,debug,shh"

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))          

print ("web3 =", web3.version.api) #4.2.1
print(web3.shh) #error occurs
```

When I try to run following code above, I am having following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dd.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(web3.shh)
AttributeError: 'Web3' object has no attribute 'shh'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
from web3.shh import Shh
Shh.attach(web3, "shh")
print(web3.shh)
```